# Text doesn't wrap an image in wordpress post

Tags: html, css

It has a very basic code and i'm sure i'm missing something. What is it?

```
<div class="span8" id="pagecs">
<?php the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div> 
</div>

#pagecs {
font-family: 'Goudy Bookletter 1911', serif;
color: #405160;
}
```

Comment: You want [CSS floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: Please post HTML when asking about CSS, not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Stefan says in the comments your missing the css floats for example:

```
#pagecs .entry-content img {
    float:left;
}
```

will align the image left.. and for good measure you can place some margins on it for spacing if you require

Answer (score 0):

The align attribute is deprecated, so we'll use CSS:

```
.alignLeft {float: left;}
```